# Finding and Deleting zeroes from data

Tags: vba, excel

So I'm at novice level working with VBA and I was attempting to use this code to find zero values and delete them from my data set.

```
Sub delete_empty_cells()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCol As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 73
    iCol = 50
    For iCol = 50 To 1 Step -1
        For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
            If Cells(iCntr, 1) = 0 Then
                Range(iCol & iCntr).Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

My data set is 73 by 50, but the size can change so an explanation on how to change the size of the parsed data would be stellar. I actually have very minimal idea on what's going on here so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You'll need to utilize the variables `lastcol` and `lastrow`. Here are some ways to find these: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba

Comment: Does the above code work otherwise?

Comment: SpecialCells Method would be a good approach.

Comment: It does not throw any errors but it doesn't do what I want it to do

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, if Cell A1=0, do you want Cell A2 to shift up into it's place, leaving Cell B1 alone?  Or do you want to delete rows where all values in the row are zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sub below first **[find and replaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx)** all the zeros (Match with Whole Cell) with blanks and then remove all the blank cells using **[SpecialCells](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196157.aspx)** method;

```
Option Explicit 

Sub FindAndDeleteZeros()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant
Dim intCol As Integer
Dim intRow As Integer

fnd = "0"
rplc = ""

Set sht = ActiveSheet

  sht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
    SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

intRow = 73
 
For intCol = 1 To 50 '1st to 50th column

    sht.Range(sht.Cells(1, intCol), sht.Cells(intRow, intCol)). _ 
    SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp 

Next intCol 

End Sub
```

Look into the links provided in the comments to avoid hard-coding the last column and last row in the module.

Comment: Thank you, this did what I was looking trying to accomplish, but how does it increment rows? I see the for loop for columns but I don't understand how the rows increment.

Comment: @wazhere24 It does not loop through them. Using specialcells it finds all the empty cells and delete them. This is faster than looping through each cell and deleting them if they are empty. The reason I first find and replace zeros with blank cells is that special cell method cannot find zeros but can find blanks.

Comment: @wazhere24 look at the link for special cells, provided above.